# Cannot insert ' into my MySQL database in java

Tags: mysql

I have designed java application & mysql database. Textfield also allow to accept whole characters. MySQL database data collation is set to utf8-default & MySQL server version is 5.7. I can type ' character in textfield. But I cannot execute sql syntax with ' in my query.

ex. Name's is not working, but names is working.

Comment: Try to insert \' instead or ''

Comment: obviously, you are creating an insert string. in this case, you have to 'escape' the ' character. you find the answer there: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

Comment: Thank you all who answered & comment for my question. \' & ''(Additional ' for first one) both are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an extra ' character

If the name is O'Brain , use it as O''Brain

For example

```
Select * from employees where name like 'O''Brain'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you gave same name to your database column name, where you parsing value from the android app.

or

specify your code so we can get more idea.